# Report Server Integrated 401 unauthorised error

Tags: reporting-services, reports, reporting, integrated-mode

I have set up Report Server in Integrated mode, using the Service Account as Network Service. On the report server I can log onto the web service using my credentials just fine. However when I try and access anything with reports on the site collection it gives me a 401 unauthorised error. Any ideas? It also gives me the same error if the service account is my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

need to debug it. Open developer tool and go to Network Tab. click on status tab and press the red record button. and then refresh the page. the status table will have different rows loaded. check for which row you are getting 401 error. is it some webpart, or some particular content.

Comment: I have a report library, when I go and click on a report. It gives me 'The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Comment: report is fetching data from Db or from other server where you dont have access.

Comment: refresh the 401 error page by following the steps mentioned above in developer tool

Comment: there is no 401 error on this

Comment: I have access to the database and the other server. I can log on and access both

Comment: Is the report library on the same server as the SharePoint instance, did you create the report library from the site collection?